# How to proceed Thread binary trees post-order traversal

Tags: data-structures, binary-tree, postorder

I want to make a post-order traversal in the thread binary tree.

If I want to do a post-order traversal, not a recursive one,

For terminal nodes, I can move them by inserting the next node address in the link to an empty child node field.

But in the case of parent node must be moved any way if I don't get the hang of things constantly.

For example, in the case of "A B * C D / -", I can go 'B' -> '*' to use B's right empty link field(thread).

But when I go '*' -> 'C' or '/' -> '-'

'*' and '/' both link fields are full by child node. I don't know how to proceed.

Please let me know how you can proceed.

**Parent node's links that use tree links (doesn't use thread links) are fulled.**

**How can I go to Parent node's Parent node.**

Comment: In a threaded binary tree, you usually maintain flags to tell you whether the right and left links are tree links or thread links.

Comment: That should say "child links or thread links."